# How to call a method or phone number using notifcation addAction

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-pendingintent

I'm trying to call this method` Or more importantly call a number when I press the addAction button.

```
public void call(){
        Log.i(TAG,"Attempting Call "+emergecyNumber);
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        //callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +emergecyNumber));
        startActivity(callIntent);
    }`
```

My notifcation

> public void startFallNotification(String name, String loc){
>
> ```
>     Intent intent = new Intent(); //create intent for notifcation
>     PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
>
>
>     Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
>             .setVibrate(new long[]{1000,1000,1000,1000,1000}) //sets vibrate
>            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
>              //sets sound
>             .setTicker(name+" has fallen at "+loc)
>             .setContentTitle(name+" has fallen at "+loc)
>             .setContentText(n+" has fallen")
>             .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
>             .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Call Now", null)
>             .setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();
>
>     NotificationManager notiMan = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
>     notiMan.notify(0,noti);
> }
> ```

Comment: Are you trying to call the method on the notification's click? Specify your call hierarchy and flow.

Comment: My main goal is when something happens, I get a notification, the notification has a button to call a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `PendingIntent` with the CALL action and provide that when you call `addAction()` on the `Notification`. Like this:

```
// This activity will be started when the user clicks on the notification
Intent intent = new Intent(); //create intent for notifcation
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

// Create a PendingIntent for the CALL action
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +emergecyNumber));
PendingIntent callPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, callIntent, 0);


Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setVibrate(new long[]{1000,1000,1000,1000,1000}) //sets vibrate
       .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
         //sets sound
        .setTicker(name+" has fallen at "+loc)
        .setContentTitle(name+" has fallen at "+loc)
        .setContentText(n+" has fallen")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Call Now", callPendingIntent)
        .setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();
```